# Download html textarea content as a file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a project where the requirement is to download a textarea content as a .txt file on a wordpress site.

After searching previous questions, I got below code which marked as a correct answer.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit">Download Text</input>
</form>

<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {   

$text = $_POST['text'];
print ($text);

$filename = 'test.txt';
$string = $text;

$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($fp, $string);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
header('Content-type: application/txt');
readfile('test.txt');

 }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

But for me it is not creating a .txt file. please help me to identify the issue

Comment: Try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually creates a file on the server and it does not get deleted afterwards. If the code failed, it is possible that you didn't have permission to write on your server. You can trim your code down to the following so as no file is generated in the process:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text']))
 {
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
   header('Content-type: application/txt');
   echo $_POST['text'];
   exit; //stop writing
 }
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Download Text</input>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Firstly, you should output the file before printing anything on screen and secondly, you forgot to add `name="submit"` to your original code. I didn't use it here, but I included for you to get an idea.

---

In the WordPress Context:
Add this to your `functions.php` or plugin file:

```
function feed_text_download(){
if(isset($_POST['text_to_download']))
 {
   header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
   header('Content-type: application/txt');
   echo $_POST['text_to_download'];
   exit; //stop writing
 }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'feed_text_download');
```

Add the form to one of your template files or in the HTML editor of your post:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <textarea name="text_to_download" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Download Text</input>
</form>
```

It should be good :)

---

**EDIT: Add Filename**

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label>Filename:<input type="text" name="filename" /></label>
  <label>Text:<textarea cols="100" name="text_to_download" rows="20"></textarea></label>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download Text" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
function feed_text_download() {
  if ( isset( $_POST['text_to_download'] ) && isset( $_POST['filename'] ) ) {

    $filename = sanitize_file_name( $_POST['filename'] );

    header( 'Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );
    header( 'Content-type: application/txt' );
    echo $_POST['text_to_download'];
    exit; //stop writing
  }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'feed_text_download' );
```

Comment: This code giving me error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\Users\aratnan\Desktop\wordpress\InstantWP_4.3\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\freshlife\template-fullwidth.php:7) in C:\Users\aratnan\Desktop\wordpress\InstantWP_4.3\iwpserver\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-exec-php\wp-exec-php.php(652) : eval()'d code on line 4'

Comment: You're using it in your `template-fullwidth.php`, and the theme is already outputting things before your code is run.

Comment: @acr I updated my answer. It's just a Proof of Concept on how to do it. You might want to add a nonce or do security checks.

Comment: @ RRikesh      : Its working fine..Thanks.. Is there anyway user can choose the filename while saving instead of test.txt ?

Answer (score 3):

Modified little bit in your code.

First put  your php code

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {   

    $text = $_POST['text'];
    print ($text);

    $filename = 'test.txt';
    $string = $text;

    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $string);
    fclose($fp);

    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.txt');
    header('Content-type: application/txt');
    readfile('test.txt');
    die; //modified code 
     }
    ?>
```

after that put your html code

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">Download Text</input>
</form>
```

add name attribute in submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code, that will help you:

```
<?php  ob_start();?>
<html>
<body>
<?php

     if(isset($_POST['tarea'])){
     $filename = 'test.txt';
     $data = $_POST['tarea']; 
     header("Cache-Control: public");
     header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
     header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
     header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
     echo $data;
     exit;
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<textarea name="tarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit">     
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: : it giving error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent` after clicking the download button

Comment: Are you getting warning, in my example?

Comment: Call ob_start() at the top of the script to buffer the output.